# How do churches make Christians believe in robotic archbishops?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, religion, robots

In the immediate future humans and androids coexist amicably, the androids have human level intelligence. In order to accommodate for one of the fastest growing religions in the world we introduce robotic archbishops fluent in all versions of the Bible, everything looks all right except for one obstacle: artificial Christians.

Method must be legitimate and I shall have faith in your intention.

Disclaimer: I am no Christian nor atheist, however neither do I encourage any misdeed against any religion.

Comment: If the robots have human levels of intelligence, do they believe in a god too?

Comment: @Harry David: We are their god! Maybe  our god is their god too?

Comment: "The Mystery of Faith..." (Religious Reference).

Comment: There are arguments that christians make about this stuff, but for at least Catholicism the word of the Pope should be enough.

Comment: Maybe if you explored the question how any church makes their follower believe in anything they suggest you would find your answer.

Comment: I think the question requires clarification. What do you want me to answer? Religious followers don't believe in bishops, but gods. Are you talking about what religion your androids might have? Or the problems human followers might have in android bishops? Is it about faith and robots? Is it about how society percieves robots that do believe? Please clarify the question.

Comment: @Durakken - Not so.  Women aren't allowed to be priests today in the Catholic church, let alone robots.  If tomorrow the stance suddenly changed and it was "anything goes" you would definitely have a big schism.  Most likely if the Pope declared such a thing you would see a great reformation around Eastern Rite Catholicism, which would declare a greater divide and probably sever all ties.

Comment: @Andreas Heese: a archbishop role is to enforce rules on top of housekeeping loosely put, my question is how can the church and followers permit a robot to become a disciplinary master also loosely speaking? I'm not saying the robot can personify god or argue if robot do believe in god because even the term believe is virtual or non-existence.

Comment: @user6760 It is not that easy... anyone that is a christian priest or any other kind of christian cleric stands *In persona Christi*. So the robot **MUST** be able to personify one of the personas of god, namely Christ, the son (the other two personas being the father and the holy ghost), otherwise you will not even get to the point where you can start worrying about the public accepting these robots as clerics. See my answer for many more questions that need answering by you before we can give an answer to your question.

Comment: People argue about religion, gods, and whether we have "souls" or not. How can something which we put together from plastics, and some rare metals have a ***soul***? It has ***software***. It may be "sentient", but I would argue that it mimics life through cleverly programmed algorithms, not through any sort of divine intervention. Even as a non-believer, I don't see how you could possibly spin an android as being a religious leader. Maybe that android could serve the church in some capacity (head librarian?), and maybe it might even believe that God created ***humans***, but no more.

Comment: If I were you first I would have robots as they gain intelligence express interest in spiritual concepts and believes.  introduce a small group of robots who have on there own chosen to convert to Christianity. They began movement of robots Christian dedicated on reach both humans and robots to the Good News.

Comment: then once the movement becomes big enough have the excepted by a famous and trust Christian leader like the pope.  Once this happens people might be more excepting of a robot bishop

Comment: I was going to answer on this question but it was closed if it reopens I will convert these series of comments into an actual answer this is going to be rather confusing since its essentially an answer in the comment section but as I said this question is put on hold

Comment: I'm going to be doing this in the series of comments because the word limit for a single comment is too Limited for my answer.

Comment: Many of the other answers Express disbelief that a robot even a sentient one would be accepted into church much less become a bishop. Well I have to agree this is unlikely it is not impossible as they think. In fact something similar has happened before.

Comment: Take the story of Cornelius the Centurion, as recorded the scriptures. When early Christianity started it was exclusively a Jewish religion all convert were Jewish and the apostles and other leaders only preach to Jews, the idea of gentiles becoming Christians wasn't even something that they thought of.

Comment: This all changed with Cornelius the Centurion. According to the scriptures Cornelius was interested in Christianity and sought out and high-ranking and well-respected church leader Peter the Apostle.

Comment: According to the story recorded in the Bible after Peter met with Cornelius the Holy Spirit fell upon Cornelius. Seeing this as a sign from God Peter formerly baptize him into the church.

Comment: A little while later he publicly acknowledged Cornelius as a member of the church and expressed his support for the church to convert other gentiles as well. At the time all the church leaders were of course Jewish.  But within a generation most of the church leaders were of Gentile origin.

Comment: With some subtle changes you could use this story as an origin for your robotic Archbishop

Comment: Consider a robot shows interest in Christianity and seeks out a highly trusted and respected Church leader ( perhaps the Pope). After spending some time with the leader, the robot performs either a miracle or if not at least something that is perceived as a miracle by those who see it. Seen this as a sign the church leader formally accept the robot into the church. And expressing support for him publicly.

Comment: Seeing no way to disprove the miracle and not wanting to contradict such a highly respected and trusted religious figure the other church members accept him into the church.

Comment: As a member of the church there is no formal barrier preventing him from becoming a Archbishop. It would take time but as a robot who doesn't age as long as any damages is regular repaired he has all the time in the world to rise through the ranks of the church into the office of Archbishop especially if other robots join the church.

Comment: @user6760 again I want to apologize for putting all this in the comment section but I could see no other alternative

Comment: No worry thanks for the interesting answer anyway.

Comment: @user6760 yes I mainly focused on how a robot could be accepted into the church because that the difficulty part. Once he is expected becoming Archbishop is pretty strate forward.

Answer (score 8):

## The Eighth Day Debate, a much bigger can of worms

For in six days God made the heavens and the earth, the sea, and all that is in them, but he rested on the seventh day.

**Then, on the eighth day, man made new life in his own image...**

Mankind has just assumed the role of God, creating life without the help of God. You are going to have a theological debate like no other.

- These robots, do they have a soul?
- Are they "born" with or without Original Sin?
- Do they need Jesus's sacrifice on the cross to be redeemed?
- Does it even matter since these robots cannot really die, because of their corporeal body is destroyed, we just pull a new one from the assembly line and load it with the latest backup?
- Is it even right for man to create life or is that the sole prerogative of God?
- If God is the only one allowed to create and destroy life, are these robots then an abomination or simply not alive?
- If they are not alive, what are they then, since they are not really dead either?

So, **long** before you get to the point of asking whether these robots may stand [**In persona Christi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_persona_Christi) or not, you will have one hell of a debate whether they will even be considered **persons** by the church! And this is not mentioning the myriad of **legal** and **human rights** issues that stem from the advent of artificial humans.

> *If only you could hear yourselves... 'Human rights.' Why the very name is racist.* 
>  — Azetbur, Star Trek VI: The Undiscovered Country

So before you get to **this** question, you must untangle all the other ones before: in the eyes of the state and the world, do robots have "human" rights? Are they considered persons? Are they considered citizens? And then in the eyes of the church, the same questions. And finally, the church must answer: may a robot stand **In persona Christi** or not?

**Then**... when you have untangled all that, then we can start talking about a marketing campaign on how to make people accept robot bishops. But before that, we really cannot answer your question because humans' attitude towards robots depend very heavily on these things.

Comment: Well said. There's a lot of issues which must be overcome before the OP's questions can even be addressed.

Comment: I see your points how can my robot prove "he" has a soul but we can use a donated DNA to encode the bible, with human level intelligent and built in intuition v2.0 I'm sure your feeling would betray you once you attend 1 session.

Comment: @user6760 Like I said: this is not for me to figure out. :) Sorry to be an arse but **you** are the one building a world here. And in doing so, **you** need to explore this whole issue of artificial life and all the ethical and theological implications it entails. You will not have a credible world until you have given some backstory as how it came to be that robots are a part of everyday life, and how people - and the church in particular - regard them. Side-note: I for one am looking forward to when this happens in real life because I think it will be very interesting and turbulent times. :D

Comment: @AndreiROM Ah, thanks for the edit, just what I needed. :)

Comment: Back story? Been there done that countless of time and eventually my question got silenced every time, sorry to sneak in an opportunity to rant... I admit I enjoy seeing reactions of people from all walks of life even the bot I should be ashamed of myself!

Comment: No problem! And you're right about ***"interesting and turbulent times"***. The geek in me really wants AI's, but at the same time it's so, so scary that we could potentially unleash an entity into our cyberspace which might go "Cylon" on its human overlords ... All in all, I almost want it to be some other generation's problem. Not to mention that we are _not_ mature enough to navigate the issues you mentioned.

Comment: @user6760 If your questions get closed, then you are doing something wrong. I am sorry but them are the breaks. We are offering you our time, our attention and our effort to help you along in your quests to build an interesting world. Then the **least** you must do is to help us along by making your questions clear and **answerable**. As it stands in this particular instance, you have not done that. You say you have made this backstory already; well I do not see that backstory here. It is all fine and well that **you** know it, but how do you expect **me** to know it?! I am not a mind-reader.

Comment: @AndreiROM '*we are not mature enough to navigate the issues you mentioned*' All the more interesting those times will be. If we were all prepared and ready and **mature** enough to have an ethical debate on the status of artificial life, things would be over quickly and very boringly. But as long as we have things such as **churches** muddling up the waters, we can expect a long and very "lively" debate. :D

Comment: ***"would be over quickly and very boringly"*** - as opposed to World War 5, and maybe a nuclear conflict? Oh, the excitement, lol. Or should we call it a **"lively debate"** instead? Us humans are so silly.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors while I agree with you that the above questions would have to be answered by the church if robot are to become member, however these questions don't need to be answered before they become accepted into the church. Take for example the acceptance of Gentiles into the early church. The acceptance of Gentiles into the church raised a lot of questions that needed to be answered. Such as does a gentile automatically become a Jew when he converts to Christianity? Does a gentile who converts do Christianity also have to keep the Jewish law? And so on

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors while all these questions where answered officially by the church not happen till after several of their leaders begin to accept Gentiles into the church. It's possible that a similar thing could happen if robots are to be accepted into the church.

Comment: @BryanMcClure For the sake of being able to answer OPs question, we need to know how the development of sentient machines came to be, and the debate surrounding them, and what their current status is. In short we need to know the attitude of people, and what they feel about these machines.

Answer (score 5):

In a realistic world, you're going to end up with lots of differing opinions.

1. Some people will welcome the androids with open arms, and things will continue as normal.
2. Some people will argue that androids aren't real people, and discriminate against them.
3. Some people will argue that androids might be people, but they shouldn't be allowed into certain positions, such as the clergy or public office.

What will actually happen is that people from groups 2 and 3 will likely dominate at first, and androids will be second-class citizens for a while. Depending on your story and the people involved, they will likely end up either totally enslaved or as equals to humanity after decades or centuries. A quick Google search on racial inequality should give you plenty of material on what kind of struggles these androids will face.

In this case, you're obviously going for equality. So your story is probably set after androids are legally entitled to the same civil liberties as humans. However, you're likely to still have a number of type 2 and 3 people who resist. Regardless of civil rights, the government won't likely force people to worship alongside androids, so there's a decent chance the major religions will fragment into a number of sub-religions, with differing views towards androids.

My guess is the type 3 people will eventually just get over the whole thing and the vast majority of people from the religion will allow androids as clergy. But you'll still have smaller offshoots with varying limitations on androids, as well as a dwindling, but ever present, number of type 2 groups.

It's also possible the religion just outright refuses to have anything to do with androids, in which case there isn't a good solution here. But "Christians" aren't just one group of exactly-the-same mind. So really you have to apply all of the above to each denomination of Christian, and you'll end up with groups who fall all over the place with regard to androids.

The [largest group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Christian_denominations_by_number_of_members) of Christians are [Catholic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholicism#Catholic_Church) (1.2 billion people), so if you're trying to tell the story within a single "religion", I'd start there. They all report to the [Pope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope) in Rome, so as long as Rome says androids are cool, most Catholics will accept them. However, it may take time before all Catholic churches accept androids in practice, and you may well end up with splinter factions.

There are 800 million protestants, but they're broken up into a lot of smaller sects with sometimes radically different views. For example, there are about 90 million Baptists, and 90 million Lutherans, each of which has further subdivisions, and each of which has pretty substantial differences from the other group. These groups are better choices if you're looking for a variety of stances on androids, but not so great for your purposes.

Comment: Androids would also have to be somehow limited in computing capacities. Otherwise they will simply outcompete humans after couple upgrades.

Comment: I don't think Catholics follow the pope as devoutly as you think (no matter what the official rules are). The Pope has said that human evolution and accepting homosexuals is cool but there's still tens of millions of Catholics that haven't gone along with it.

Answer (score 4):

## It Wouldn't Happen

Archbishops don't just happen.  The rise up through a series of elected ranks and only do so based on their behaviour and how well they're respected along the way.

Simply imposing a new bishop on people just wouldn't work out, human or android any more than dragging a tramp off the street and making him Pope.

Comment: Point taken about how you can't suddenly impose ready-made Archbishops, but if robots can be baptized as Christians (specifically Catholics in this scenario), presumably they can rise to be Archbishops *eventually*. There might be a problem regarding their gender or lack of it.

Comment: @Lostinfrance - Taking this question back to the logical root, we're asking whether androids can believe in God and whether humans can believe that androids can believe in God.  It's an unanswerable question.

Comment: I understand there are strict rules to appoint a new archbishop and can you state in your answer that my robot has been disqualified due to a particular clause listed in the contract or the like thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Who says the bishops are artificial Christians? As in your story God would have seen fit to grant to androids intelligence, free will, and the ability to understand the gospel then they would clearly fall under the divine mandate to proclaim the gospel to every creature and baptize those that believe. Potentially a debate regarding the necessity of baptism relative to determining if they have fallen from grace.

Stories that have dealt with this or very similar to this include:

John C. Wright's The Eschaton Sequence (Catholic bent)

"[Avek who is distributed](http://lit.mormonartist.net/2016/02/avek-who-is-distributed/)" by  Steven Peck (Mormon, included because it deals precisely (and solely) with the question.)

"That Leviathan, Whom Thou Hast Made" by Erik James Stone (Nebula Award for Best Novelette) 
Among many others.

*I was looking up the Catholic debates on the subject of extra-terrestials needing baptism from the middle-ages, but [Pope Francis has spoken of aliens and baptism in 2014.](http://www.christianpost.com/news/pope-francis-talks-about-aliens-says-he-would-welcome-martians-to-receive-baptism-119630/)

Comment: I knew this answer will come out so I edited my question.

Comment: If I am not answering your question you haven't clarified enough still.

Comment: Well since the Pope has agreed...

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR - Make an official office called Proxy to the Archbishop, and over time this "proxy" will gain as much power and status as the Archbishop himself.

---

**What to do**: Just say that the robots are a proxy or representative for a real human Archbishop somewhere and anything that the android Archbishop would say or do needs to be treated as if the real Archbishop were saying it or doing it.

**How to get people to accept it**: Make sure the human Archbishop being represented is someone that everyone loves and admires. Like a mother Teresa type character. Convince people that this man could do so much more good if only he had representation elsewhere. Make a vid of an android feeding starving kids or leading a mass in the name of Archbishop So-and-so. Then once you have the popular opinion on your side get someone high up in the church to make an official office of Non-human Proxy to the Archbishop. At first the androids will be entirely associated with this human Archbishop so they'll have no real power or office on their own, just the power of representation.

**The long game**: However, over time, and this is the funny part, people will conflate the proxy with the human they're representing and the androids will become de facto Archbishops with all the power therein. Even after the human Archbishop has died the androids can say things like "Well the Archbishop *would have wanted* this or that to be done, so do it." And most people will.

**Why it would work**: It's already being done (kinda)! Maybe not through androids, but through *simulcasts*. Sometimes there's a big-name preacher that wants to plant another church but he can't be in two places at once. So instead of placing a different autonomous preacher at each church location he instead will do a live broadcast of himself to each one. So people are drawn to these local church plants because of Mr. Big-Name's charisma and likeability, and then if they have a question or issue they bring it to the installed deacons or associate pastors who act as proxies for Mr. Big-Name.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is unlikely that the church would accept AI in this way in an immediate future. I think it'd likely be many years after AI achieve basically all human rights in society.

That being said if the story needs this acceptance to happen faster it's possible that in a world where much of science pushes away from religion that if AI for some reason was very religious in general and were quickly growing very devote population The church may use them as evidence that technology does not mean leaving religion behind.

If you want to go in a more bizarre direction you could look up the requirements for a sainthood and have the AI following a path that if it were human would lead to it being Canonized. This would of course be deeply entangled with whether or not AI die.

Ultimately I think that the bible does not currently allow for AI in religious practice. So either some large event that forces change must happen or a lot of time needs to pass...

Comment: "*Ultimately I think that the bible does not currently allow for AI in religious practice*" The Bible is surprisingly silent on this matter....

Comment: @LCIII Well odiously the concept of robots has been invented by the time of the bible

Answer (score 2):

### You'll Have to Pick Your Flavor of Christianity

Christianity is a broad term defining many specific codes and dogmas tied together only by a belief in Jesus Christ being the son of God.  **Many Chrsitian groups do not even have the concept of an Archbishop for this question to apply to them.**

Sadly for you, I believe that Catholics - the largest group - are out.  In addition to the basic issue where robots could not partake in communion (a daily requirement), the Church still does not allow **women** to be priests (let alone Bisops/Archbishops) so it seems exceedingly unlikely that they would allow robots.

I'd probably rule out the Anglicans as well.

Other groups however may be a bit more open to the idea... the trick is going to be in finding a VERY liberal group that also has Archbishops.

Not a full answer, but hopefully I've helped narrow things down a bit for you.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to have the Catholicism being practiced not the Catholicism of today, but a variation that has changed over time and divorced from most of the current practices. The version could have even been purposefully constructed, much like a video game might make a fake religion loosely based on terms and ideas from a real one. 'Archbishop,' then, would be a mere title that conjured up loose ideas of Catholicism in the people's minds. An android 'Archbishop' could be treated like a librarian with a repository of religious documents and arguments by theologians of the past and present.

Another way, perhaps, would be to have Catholicism generally intact, but it is not well known that the Archbishop was an android. If 'lifelike' androids can in some cases, whether legally or experimentally, live out their lives as if real people, then it would be possible for one to rise in the ranks. Perhaps rich billionaires could afford to 'adopt' these androids, with society never knowing whether the adoption was of a human or android. If it were considered taboo/racist to ask or check, then it might be possible to get an android Archibishop to rise through the ranks.

Answer (score 0):

I think one main problem might be whether they are able to eat and drink and by that take the *host/housel/altar bread and whine aka the blood and flesh of Christ.

> John 6:53 Truly, truly, I say to you, unless you eat the flesh of the Son of Man and drink his blood, you have no life in you.

I can't see a Catholic Archbishop who can't share into this most holy rite. And just faking it could be seen as gravest heresy.

*I'm no native speaker and had to rely on an online translator for this. Feel free to edit to the most appropriate term.

Comment: Well, he could "eat" the bread and "drink" the wine and store them inside as a proof of being close to god. He even can display them, proudly.

Comment: @Daerdemandt That's what I meant with faking it. Some might accept that while others might see it as heresy.